# How to get an array of values (multiple values) from one xpath selector?

Tags: python, xpath

I want to extract both 'link text' and 'link address' of all links in a website. what i want is to extract this data at once and saving it in an object.

```
# here is what i tried in python: 
urls = response.xpath('//a[@class="link-on-click grayhover"]/@href|/span/text()').extract()

// here is what the html code looks like: 
<div>
    <a class="link-on-click grayhover" 
        href="/brows/cars">
        <span>cars list</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
 {url : "/brows/cars", text:'cars list'}
```

Comment: There's no `'buy cars'` in your html; did you mean `cars list`?

Comment: And is your result output intended to be a dictionary?

Comment: @JackFleeting yes. dictionary is better. but tuple is acceptable. I don't want to searc in the response more than one time to get the result faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get values in a list of dictionaries as below:

```
my_list = []
links = response.xpath('//a[@class="link-on-click grayhover"]')
for link in links:
    my_list.append({'url': link.xpath('./@href').extract_first(), 'text': link.xpath('./span/text()').extract_first()})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this gets you there:

```
source = """
<div>
<a class="link-on-click grayhover" 
    href="/brows/cars">
    <span>cars list</span>
</a>
```

"""

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(source)
car_dict = {}
for ref in doc.xpath('//a'):    
   url = ref.get("href")
   for car in ref.xpath('//span'):
      car_text = car.text
   car_dict.update({'url':url,'text':car_text})
print(car_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'url': '/brows/cars', 'text': 'cars list'}
```

There are probably ways to streamline this (comprehensions, etc.), but it should do for the time being.

Comment: thank you for the answer. needs to add a dot at the beginning of xpath string.